# EasyAdmin 3 : Nested forms

Tags: symfony4, easyadmin

I'm trying to embed forms into forms. In my case :  I want to embed Period and Price form into Offer form into Poi form. The architecture :

- Poi form

  - Offer form

    - Price form
    - Period form

Relations:

- Poi entity has relation OneToMany with Offer entity
- Offer entity has relation OneToMany with Price entity and ManyToMany with Period
  entity.

I've been looking for solution for couple of days and I really need help, so if someone could help me it will be great.

**1. First test : usage of CollectionField**
In my PoiCrudController :

```php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable {
    $offers = CollectionField::new('offers')
            ->setFormTypeOptions([
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ])
            ->setEntryIsComplex(false)
            ->setCustomOptions([
                'allowAdd' => true,
                'allowDelete' => true,
                'entryType' => 'App\Form\OfferType',
                'showEntryLabel' => false,
            ]),
```

In OfferType :

```php
class OfferType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    
        $builder
            ->add('description', CollectionType::class, array(
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'entry_type' => TextEditorType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                  'label' => false,
                ],
                'label' => 'Description',
              ))

            ->add('createdAt')
            ->add('updatedAt')
            ->add('periods')
            ->add('poi')
        ;
    }
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE => The "App\Entity\Poi" entity has a repositoryClass set to "App\Entity\PoiRepository", but this is not a valid class. Check your class naming. If this is meant to be a service id, make sure this service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service".**

If I replace `'entryType' => 'App\Form\OfferType',` with `'entryType' => 'App\Form\PoiType' in PoiCrudController,` and add this code in PoiType :

```php
class PoiType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    
        $builder
            ->add('offers', CollectionType::class, array(
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'entry_type' => TextType::class, // cette ligne pose problème
                'entry_options' => [
                  'label' => false,
                ],
                'label' => 'Offres',
              ))
```

Then the Poi form is nested into Poi form where the field 'offer' appears.
If I replace `'entry_type' => TextType::class` with `'entry_type' => TextEditorType::class,` a new error appears :

**ERROR MESSAGE : Impossible to access an attribute ("customOptions") on a null variable.
in vendor\easycorp\easyadmin-bundle\src\Resources\views\crud\form_theme.html.twig (line 424)
{% set numOfRows = form.vars.ea_crud_form.ea_field.customOptions.get('numOfRows') %}**

**2. Second test : usage of CollectionField**

In PoiCrudController :

```php
    CollectionField::new('offers', 'Offres')
                ->allowAdd() 
                ->allowDelete()
                ->setEntryIsComplex(true)
                ->setEntryType(OfferCrudController::class)
            ->setFormTypeOptions([
                'by_reference' => 'false' 
            ]),
```

**ERROR MESSAGE => Could not load type "App\Controller\Admin\OfferCrudController": class does not implement "Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface.**
My forms implement AbstractType so...

**3. Third test : usage of AssociationField**

In PoiCrudController :

```php
    AssociationField::new('offers')
                ->setFormTypeOptions([
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'allow_add' => true
                ]),
```

**ERROR MESSAGE => An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType": The option "allow_add" does not exist**
=>Issue #3528 [https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3528][2]

Answer (score 9):

I've been struggling with this issue for a long time myself, and I've finally found a solution.

I've chosen the **Fist test** pathway, but using **Second test** properties:

The CollectionField creating remains the same, just set `OfferType` form type istead of the `OfferCrudController` as the `EntryType`.

```php
    CollectionField::new('offers', 'Offres')
            ->allowAdd() 
            ->allowDelete()
            ->setEntryIsComplex(true)
            ->setEntryType(OfferType::class)
        ->setFormTypeOptions([
            'by_reference' => 'false' 
        ]),
```

Then edit the **OfferType**:

```php
class OfferType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(...) // whatever you want
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Offer::class,

        ]);
    }
}
```

Adding the configureOptions method solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Allow add should be in the Collection Field and not in the AssociationField.

Comment: @MoubarZakaria please avoid to give a single line answer, you could have posted in comment box.